# Get file name in WiX

Tags: file, wix, installation, substring

I am currently working on an installer for my software using the WiX toolset. Today I faced the problem of getting only the name of an file. In the main file I include another .wxs file, which is generated automatically and defines the files of the application. In this main file I want to get the file name of  a file referenced in the included file. I know, that

```
[#FILE-ID]
```

returns the full path to the file with the specific id, but how can I get only the file name?

Is there an similar opportunity or are there any substring operations in Wix? I did not find any solution in the internet yet and hope, you can help me.

Comment: You've shown a Windows Installer expression. There is no way in that context. But if you explain why you need the file name and how you get to the point of knowing the file id without know the name perhaps we can help.

Comment: I currently use this expression in my installer and it is working for the full path.
Although the wix-file and so the file id is generated automatically, the id of a specific file never changes.
I need to know only the file name for specifying the IE Version that should be used in my application (see [link](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2011/May/21/Web-Browser-Control-Specifying-the-IE-Version).